# How to create a safe offline single sign on

Tags: c++, single-sign-on

I am currently writing a firmware for an embedded device which acts as an human-machine-interface in an (aftermarket) automobile environment.

The device has got a service menu which shall only be accessible to specific personnel, which is secured by a device specific pin-code, which is generated randomly in production, burned on the device and stored in a database for the personnel to retrieve. Within the service menu, the user is e.g. able to manually change states and also overwrite limits for regulation functions etc.

However it might be necessary for any user to get to that menu in an error case, e.g. if they get stuck in a remote place and have a faulty sensor or whatever. Therefore I would like to create a kind of single-sign-in for the devices. My idea is, that the device creates a code and displays it to the user. The user then calls the service team which can create a pin valid for this device in this current state (the code displayed).

I don't want it to be too easy to figure out, so that anybody will be able to crack the algorithm of code generation. I cannot use any online functionality, as the users - as mentioned - may be in a remote place.

I was thinking about creating a table of random numbers and implementing it in the firmware (like 1-10k of pins and the device displays an index and the service teams just looks up the pin for that index) But I feel like there is a better solution to that problem.

**My question:**
What is a safe algorithm to compute a 4 digit (1000 - 9999) pin-code based on a random number (~6 digits hexadecimal) and (optionally) a 6 byte large serialnumber?

Comment: Some things to consider: What happens if the user tries all codes between 0000 and 9999? What happens if the user reboots the device until they get the random number that matches a pin number they already know?

Comment: You should consult cryptographers. I'll suggest asking here https://crypto.stackexchange.com/. This is not a C++ specific problem